# Write a PL/SQL Script that fills a table with the help of a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I write a PL / SQL program that creates and fills a table for example let's call the table "TABEMP1", it fills it with data from any other table.

What I have so far;

```
set serveroutput on
set verify off
DECLARE
Cursor cur_emp IS SELECT * FROM EMP;
v_emp EMP%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_emp;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_emp INTO v_emp;
        EXIT WHEN cur_emp%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line('Ename: ' || v_emp.ename || ' Empno: ' || v_emp.empno);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_emp;
END;
/
```

Comment: You only want to achieve that using a cursor? There are other ways without cursors

Comment: Please tag the correct rdms.

Comment: @Hawk and how do you do that without a cursor? thanks!

Comment: create table ... as ... see: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table2.php

Answer (score 1):

No need for a cursor, using Native SQL with [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://psoug.org/definition/execute_immediate.htm) you can achieve that with flexible features:

```
DECLARE
lv_src_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'EMP';
pi_new_table_name  VARCHAR2(30) := 'emp_copy';
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||pi_new_table_name||' AS SELECT * FROM '||pi_src_table_name;
END;
/
```

You can turn that into procedure and pass the two parameters with any original/copy tables names you want

Answer (score 0):

In this case you dont need a PLSQL to achieve. A single SQL statement will be more effective. Hope below snippet helps.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_EMP
AS
SELECT * FROM EMP;
```